# Defining substitution by structural recursion

Tags: logic, proof-writing, recursion

For a term u, let $u{x\atop t}$ be the expression obtained from $u$ by replacing the variable $x$ by the term $t$. Define $u{x\atop t}$ by recursion on $u$.

Not really sure how to start this one.  I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you know what a definition by recursion on the shape of a formula looks like?

Comment: @HenningMakholm No, not really.  I'm a little fuzzy on the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Begin by defining $u[{x\atop t}]$ when $u$ is a variable or a constant.  The first clause will be $x[{x\atop t}]=t$; there will be two more clauses, one for the case where $u$ is a variable other than $x$, and one for the case where $u$ is a constant.  After that comes the recursion clause, where you'll define $f(t_1,\dots,t_n)[{x\atop t}]$ in terms of the $t_i[{x\atop t}]$, where $f$ is an $n$-ary function symbol and $t_1,\dots,t_n$ are terms.  Every clause here can be found by just thinking about what substitution of $t$ for $x$ should do to variables, to constants, and to compound terms.

(If you or your teacher or your textbook had the good taste to treat constants as $0$-ary function symbols, then you don't need a separate clause for the case where $u$ is a constant; it will be covered by the $n=0$ case of the recursion clause.)

Comment: I'll see what I can do with your approach.  Thank you!